# HttpGet request string parameters getting initialised as null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have written an api endpoint in asp.net core and calling the endpoint via postman.
The endpoint takes two string parameters. Unfortunately when i debug the code, the parameters are coming as null. Not sure why.

I am calling using the following url using postman

https://localhost:44355/v1.0/selfkyc/multi/masterdata/en-gb

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("multi/{applicationId}/{languageId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTranslation([FromRoute] string applicationCode, [FromRoute] string languageCode)
    {
        var translation = await _selfKycService.GetTranslationAsync(applicationCode, languageCode);

        if (translation != null)
        {
            return Ok(translation);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the inconsistency between your attribute routing parameters and the controller accepting parameters.
[image: Parameter comparison]
For more attribute routing operations, please check the official documentation：
[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Controller's method parameters needs to match with route parameters name.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("multi/{applicationId}/{languageId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTranslation([FromRoute] string applicationId, [FromRoute] string languageId)
 {
      var translation = await _selfKycService.GetTranslationAsync(applicationId, languageId);

      if (translation != null)
      {
          return Ok(translation);
      }

      return NotFound();
 }
```